# Change jdk in build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I updated from java 8 to java 14 but i need change the build.xml of my project and i don't know what value i should set there.

Instead of JDK8.present i should set to JDK14.present
and source="1.8" target="1.8" /> to what?

````
        <fail message="Ant 1.8.2 is required. But your version is ${ant.version} and if you are using Eclipse probably is outdated.">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <antversion atleast="1.8.2" />
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
        <available classname="java.util.stream.Stream" property="JDK8.present" />
        <fail unless="JDK8.present" message="Java 1.8 is required. But your version is Java ${ant.java.version} and probably JDK is not installed." />
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="checkRequirements" description="Create the output directories.">
        <delete dir="${build.bin}" quiet="true" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.bin}" />
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="init" description="Export the files to the output directory.">
        <sync todir="${build.dist}" includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="dist" />
        </sync>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="dist" description="Compile the source.">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" destdir="${build.bin}" compiler="modern" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" />
    </target>```
````

Answer (score 0):

These bits

```
<available classname="java.util.stream.Stream" property="JDK8.present" />
<fail unless="JDK8.present" message="Java 1.8 is required. But your version is Java ${ant.java.version} and probably JDK is not installed." />
```

Are the parts that detect JDK 1.8.  Notice that they only do so by detecting if a class is available (as that class was added in JDK 1.8)

A better way might be to use the Ant propery `${ant.java.version}` which should return back `14` for Java 14.  They abandoned the `1.x` prefix in Java 9.

Comment: I did change to source="14" target="14" /> but when i try build it says build.xml:61: Java 14 is required. But your version is Java 14 and probably JDK is not installed. I have set Java jdk kit 14 / bin in environmental variables.

Comment: So for example to understand how i should use the ${ant.java.version} ? In source=""? PS. I think i made it i had forgot a property="JDK14.present" /> to 8 version i changed it and it compile now.

Comment: @GeorgeClouney Glad you figured it out.  In the older days, people would check if something was present to see if there was a new Java version.  These days, Ant does a better job of detecting the Java version directly.